# Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle

I use android studio 2.3.2 and here is my gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
}
dependencies {
}
```

I also updated gradle, but I still have problem to run the project!

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
}
dependencies {
}
```

Those belong in the module-level `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`), not in the top-level `build.gradle` file.

You may want to create a new empty project in Android Studio and see what it puts into `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` before proceeding.